# How would I make a large website with React, if React makes SPAs

Tags: reactjs

I want to use react js to make a news website with hundreds of articles. As I understand it, react makes single-page-applications. Surely it is not feasibly to include hundreds of articles in a single-page-application, so how could this be done?

Comment: Being a single-page application from a technical perspective is **not** the same thing as only having one page from the user's perspective.

Comment: Although you can use reactjs for this, I would recommend something like NextJs in this case. It is way better for these types of sites. This is an excellent blog template built on top of nextjs that takes care of pretty much all the SEO requirements (https://github.com/timlrx/tailwind-nextjs-starter-blog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely use react to make a single page application which shows hundreds of articles.

The term single-page application describes how the articles are loaded when the user moves between the articles. In a multi-page application, every article will be its own html file. When the user clicks to go to a new article, your server sends a brand new html file, and the browser throws out the old page and shows a new one. In a single-page application, there's just one html file which is loaded at the start. As the user navigates between articles you use javascript to fetch data about that article (but not a full html file), and then you use that data to modify the existing page to look like a new page.